# Using Pandas to Make a Stacked Bar Plot Based On Sum of Values

Tags: pandas

I've got a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 Company      Product     Sale Amount   Transaction
1 Com1        Prod1       $100            T1
2 Com2        Prod1       $30             T2
3 Com1        Prod2       $120            T3
4 Com3        Prod1       $90             T4
```

I want to sum the sale amounts for each company and the put that into a bar graph with the companies on the x axis and Sales Amount on the y axis. But, I want the bar to be a stacked bar where each individual stack is a product that was sold. I'd like this sorted so the highest sum of sales will show up first and descend.

So basically, I'd be able to see a stack of products sold to a company in bar form.

Currently I'm able to print out the summed sales totals of each company like this:

```
salesTotal=pandaFrame.groupby(['Company Name'])['Sales Amount'].sum().reset_index()
salesTotal.sort_index(inplace=True)
salesTotal = salesTotal.sort_values(by=['Sales Amount'], ascending=False)
```

But this gives me a separate dataframe and loses the product info.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming there are only two products:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Setting up
Company = ['Com' + str(i) for i in list(np.random.randint(1, 15, 30))]
Product = ['Prod' + str(i) for i in list(np.random.randint(1, 3, 30))]
Sales = np.random.randint(30, 200, 30)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company': Company, 'Product': Product, 'Sales': Sales})

# Solution
df_1 = df.groupby(['Company', 'Product'])['Sales'].sum()
df_1 = df_1.unstack().fillna(0)
df_1['Total_Sales'] = df_1['Prod1'].add(df_1['Prod2'])
df_1 = df_1.sort_values('Total_Sales', ascending=False)[:10]

df_1.iloc[:, :2].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.ylabel('Sales Amount, $')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. Where orange would be one product and blue would be another.

Comment: How would I plot just the top 10 companies in terms of total sales?

Comment: I was able to do it by adding this after .sum()

.sort_values(ascending=False)[:10]

Comment: So it looks like it isn't working as I want it.
The graph I get does not include all of the items that each company sold in the stacked bar. Also, it's not sorting by the sum of the sales amount.